# Can I do this without using break in the if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have gone far ahead of my coding classes so I knew a little more than what was required when starting the semester. **EDIT** Excuse the indentation error for define function.

**EDIT** temporarily removed. thank you so much for the feedback guys. I will put it back momentarily.

Comment: Which if statement does the `else: return counter` correspond to?

Comment: @NathanHamm The `else` clause belongs to the `for` statement.

Comment: isn't that exactly the same as `str.index()` does ?

Comment: Yes. There are certain functions, he says "not allowed to use" for certain questions. He does not seem to like built-in functions very much lol.

Comment: And for the else, it is a for-else clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop instead, with a condition that's opposite of that in the `if` statement for breaking. The index `position` would be equal to the upper bound `needle_characters` if the loop finishes without breaking, so use `position == needle_characters` as an equivalent condition for the `else` clause of the original `for` loop.

Change:

```
for position in range(needle_characters):
    if haystack[counter+position] != needle[position]:
       break
else:
    return counter
```

to:

```
position = 0
while position < needle_characters and haystack[counter+position] == needle[position]:
    position += 1
if position == needle_characters:
    return counter
```